# How do I import an R-model into C#?

Tags: c#, r, unity-game-engine

I want to import a mathematical model, which is written in R, into C# (to ultimately embed it into Unity). Since I could not find a convenient way to embed R-code in C# (I tried RDotNet and R(D)COM, but it did not work) I was wondering if there exists another way to import my R-model into C# or if there is another possibility to upload my model into Unity? 
FYI: I work on a Mac.

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The equations/ODE's are written in C but solved in R (because of handy solver functions). The goal is to develop a VR Game.

Comment: Do you really want to use R inside unity ? O_O I really advise against that... what are you trying to accomplish ? Do you want to make a game or something else ?

Comment: The equations/ODE's are written in C but solved in R (because of handy solver functions). I think one could also solve them in C# but it would take quite some time. And yes, the goal is to make a VR Game out of it.

Comment: Mmh... embedding R in a VR Game is not a good solution IMO (also I really doubt it can work, mainly for portability reason)... I would investigate if there's a C# opensource library supporting ODE's that can be embedded in unity

Comment: I will search for a C# ODE solver, thanks for your advice!